# The javascript that changes the suffix text after selecting a product variant does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, woocommerce

I've tried changing the surffix text from /m2 to /szt. in javascript and it's generally half-successful. Because after loading, the price shows with the piece, but after choosing the variant, unfortunately, m2 remains. I created such a code but I don't know what's wrong with it, that it only shows the changed price in one place - an example product page https://www.styl-bruk.eu/.../obrzeze-trawnikowe-6x20x100cm/
Does anyone have an idea what could be improved?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWQJ5.png)

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const surffixElement = document.querySelector(".surffix");
  surffixElement.textContent = "/szt.";
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="woocommerce-variation-price"><span class="price"><span class="prefix">od </span><del aria-hidden="true"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>95,94&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>64,90&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi></span></ins><span class="surffix" id="suffix-id">/m2 </span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the block containing the price on the top ("14,51 zł 13,90 zł/m2") was added into the DOM after you selected a choice in the select list. So it doesn't exist when the page was loaded. That's why your JS code doesn't work with it, because it was loaded directly after the page load's, and at that moment the block doesn't exist.
So, you should execute your code JS after each change in the select list.
I will show you two examples : one contains the same problem like you and the second contains the solution.
1- The example with problem :

```js
function updateField(number) {
    let element = '<div class="woocommerce-variation-price"><span class="price"><span class="prefix">od </span><del aria-hidden="true"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>95,94&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>'+(number*10)+'&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi></span></ins><span class="surffix" id="suffix-id">/m2 </span></span></div>';
    
    $(".woocommerce-variation-price-container").html(element);
    
    if(number <= 1){
        $(".woocommerce-variation-price-container").hide();
    }else{
        $(".woocommerce-variation-price-container").show();
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const surffixElement = document.querySelector(".surffix");
    surffixElement.textContent = "/szt.";
});

$( "#pa_kolor" ).change(function() {
    updateField($(this).val());
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="pa_kolor">
    <option value="1">numéro 1</option>
    <option value="2">numéro 2</option>
    <option value="3">numéro 3</option>
    <option value="4">numéro 4</option>
</select>

<div class="woocommerce-variation-price-container">
    
</div>

<div class="woocommerce-variation-price"><span class="price"><span class="prefix">od </span><del aria-hidden="true"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>95,94&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>64,90&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi></span></ins><span class="surffix" id="suffix-id">/m2 </span></span></div>
```

2- The example with solution:

```js
function updateField(number) {
    let element = '<div class="woocommerce-variation-price"><span class="price"><span class="prefix">od </span><del aria-hidden="true"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>95,94&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>'+(number*10)+'&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi></span></ins><span class="surffix" id="suffix-id">/m2 </span></span></div>';
    
    $(".woocommerce-variation-price-container").html(element);
    
    if(number <= 1){
        $(".woocommerce-variation-price-container").hide();
    }else{
        $(".woocommerce-variation-price-container").show();
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const surffixElement = document.querySelector(".surffix");
    surffixElement.textContent = "/szt.";
});

$( "#pa_kolor" ).change(function() {
    updateField($(this).val());
    
    const surffixElement = document.querySelector(".surffix");
    surffixElement.textContent = "/szt.";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="pa_kolor">
    <option value="1">numéro 1</option>
    <option value="2">numéro 2</option>
    <option value="3">numéro 3</option>
    <option value="4">numéro 4</option>
</select>

<div class="woocommerce-variation-price-container">
    
</div>

<div class="woocommerce-variation-price"><span class="price"><span class="prefix">od </span><del aria-hidden="true"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>95,94&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>64,90&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">zł</span></bdi></span></ins><span class="surffix" id="suffix-id">/m2 </span></span></div>
```

Comment: I added the code you wrote and unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: I updated my previous comment with adding two examples. The first example contain the same problem like you and the second example contain the solution.
Can you check it with running the code snippet ?